# How to set dynamic default textarea data in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm designing a contact form and I'd like in some case (not always) pre-fill the subject and content field with data in the URLs.

That's why my view look like this:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        # Some more logic here

    else: # GET request
        contact_form = ContactForm()
        subject = request.GET.get('subject') or ""
        content = request.GET.get('content') or ""

    return render(request, 'contact.html', locals())
```

I created an `addattrs` custom filter that allow me to inject HTML attributes in HTML elements.

So, for pre-filling the subject (a classic text input), I do it like this, and it works:

```
{% with "value="|add:subject as attrs %}
    {{ contact_form.subject|addattrs:attrs }}
{% endwith %}
```

Now, I'd like to do the same thing with a textarea.
But textarea default values are not set by filling the HTML `value` attribute, they're filled that way:

```
<textarea>default texte here</textarea>
```

How could I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks/issues/7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to manipulate with HTML. Use `initial` argument of the form constructor:

```
subject = request.GET.get('subject', '')
content = request.GET.get('content', '')
contact_form = ContactForm(initial={'subject': subject, 'content': content})
```